# How to delete MongoDB databases that match specific condition?

Tags: database, mongodb

I have many databases, I can delete them one by one. But there are too many databases, How can I delete them at once.

For example, delete all databases that name has `recommend`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `db.adminCommand`

```
db.adminCommand("listDatabases").databases.forEach( function (d) {
    if (d.name == "recommend")
        db.getSiblingDB(d.name).dropDatabase();
 })
```

With this, you can add multiple conditionals for specific db.

Here list of avaliable commands:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/nav-administration/

Here more documentation about it:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.adminCommand/

Answer (score 1):

The `listDatabases` command returns all of the databases, you could iterate that list to drop the ones matching the criteria.

In the mongo shell that might look like:

```
db.adminCommand("listDatabases").databases.
    filter(d => d.name.match(/recommend/)).
    map(d => db.getSiblingDB(d.name).dropDatabase())
```